# glitchyness on avant garde font

Tags: css, fonts

I have a copyright line which is not looking good on my computer. When I am trying to open this copyright line on my computer it looks very glitchy. It looks good on fiddle but not on my computer. Is there any problem with the font ? The HTML and CSS code which I have used are:

HTML:

```
<p id="copyright"> © THE NORTHMAN COMPANY · 2017 · ALL RIGHTS RESERVED </p>
```

CSS:

```
{
    margin-bottom: 0px !important;
    height: auto;
    letter-spacing: .3em;
    color: rgb(40, 40, 41);
    font-family: "AvantGarde";
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #d3d8db;
}
```

I have attached the [image](https://s16.postimg.org/a0d02h9x1/glitchyness.png) (few alphabets doesn't look good) what I am getting on my computer.

Comment: You're going to have to expand on the meaning of "glitchy".

Comment: @MichaelArrison I have attached the image. Few alphabets doesn't look good.